# `completion-at-point-functions` and filesystem path completion

Tags: hooks, completion, comint

I want to use filesystem path completion in programming modes and their derivatives. To do so, I attempted to add the following code to my init.el:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions
                      #'comint--complete-file-name-data
                      nil 'local)))
```

However, it seems that `comint--complete-file-name-data` always returns non-nil, and prevents other completion-at-point functions from running.

What is the most natural way to solve this issue, or is there a simpler method to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Maybe you can add the function at the *end* of the hook, so it will run last.

Comment: @Drew this isn't quite what I need. According to the documentation, each function in `completion-at-point-functions` should return `nil` when it is not applicable at a point. Perhaps it is possible to write a wrapper around `comint--complete-file-name-data` which checks whether it is applicable or not, but I anticipate that there might be a more natural solution.

Comment: @NickD This indeed solves the issue; however, when the text around a point looks like a path, I would like path completion to take precedence over others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

I suddenly, realized that I did not inspect `comint--complete-file-name-data`, then while I was checking some things, I accidentally added `comint-filename-completion` to the global hook (i.e. as follows):

```lisp
(add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions #'comint-filename-completion)
```

This seems to have the right effect also. It seems that now Emacs tries completion using the functions in the local `completion-at-point-functions` first and otherwise falls back to the global value (I guess this is general Emacs behavior, but I was not aware of it before). Anyway, I would recommend this solution if you don't mind having filename completion in every buffer (also, you would still have to **load `comint` first**).

If this solution does not work for other modes, then the original answer below is still relevant for describing how to approach another solution.

END EDIT

From `ielm-complete-filename` we find that a solution is to make sure that the thing you are trying to complete is a string. There are probably better ways to ensure it, but the following is an example of a simple solution (it might be good enough)

```lisp
(defun my-filename-completion-function ()
  (when (save-excursion
      (search-backward " ")
      (forward-char)
      (looking-at "\""))
    (comint-filename-completion)))
```

So add this function to `completion-at-point-functions` instead.
I hope this solution solves the issue 'sufficiently well' (only tested it very quickly).

```lisp
(require 'comint)

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions
                      #'my-filename-completion-function
                      nil 'local)))
```

Of course, an alternative solution would be to simply use one of the in buffer completion packages [company-mode](http://company-mode.github.io/), [corfu](https://github.com/minad/corfu) or [auto-complete](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete).

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the first part of your answer (between `EDIT` and `END EDIT`) works well, at least in emacs lisp mode.

Comment: Your welcome. Indeed I did not test the 'first part' of the answer outside emacs-lisp mode. However, if in other modes the 'first part solution' does not work well, then the second part describes a possible approach to a better solution. B.t.w, personally, I would recommend you to simply use 'company-mode'.

Comment: "I guess this is general Emacs behavior, but I was not aware of it before" - this is the standard behavior for a buffer-local variable vs its global value, right? The `completion-at-point-functions` case is *not* a special case. Or am I misunderstanding?